# Hide Columns if values in range are greater and smaller than values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an automatic column hide macro if values in the range are below and above the number. The values in the Dev_Timeline range are chronological and consistent. To give a simple example. If Dev_Timeline ranges from 0 to 10 and Predev_Start is 3 and Dev_End is 8 I want columns 0,1,2 to hide and 9,10

The script below works well for the first for loop, however, the 2nd for loop continues to hide ColNum so in this scenario it would hide 3 and 4 instead of 9 and 10. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```
Sub Hide_DevCol()

Dim i, PredevStart, ColNum As Long
Dim Dev_Timeline, rCell, rRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

    ColNum = Range("Dev_Timeline").Column
    
        For Each rCell In Range("Dev_Timeline").Cells
        
            If rCell < Range("Predev_Start") Then
                Worksheets("Projections").Columns(ColNum).Hidden = True
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
            End If
        Next rCell
        For Each rCell In Range("Dev_Timeline").Cells
           If rCell > Range("Dev_End").Cells Then
              Worksheets("Projections").Columns(ColNum).Hidden = True
              ColNum = ColNum + 1
        End If
        Next rCell
        
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: One loop, and one condition: `If rCell.Value < Range("Predev_Start").Value Or rCell.Value > Range("Dev_End").Value Then`?

Comment: @bigBen I changed the loop to the following, still same result though:                    `For Each rCell In Range("Dev_Timeline").Cells
        
            If rCell.Value < Range("Predev_Start").Value Or rCell.Value > Range("Dev_End").Value Then
                Worksheets("Projections").Columns(ColNum).Hidden = True
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
            End If
        Next rCell`

Comment: Move the `ColNum = ColNum + 1` after the `End If`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one loop, and you need to increment `ColNum` regardless of whether the column gets hidden:

```
For Each rCell In Range("Dev_Timeline")

    If rCell.Value < Range("Predev_Start").Value Or rCell.Value > Range("Dev_End").Value Then
        Worksheets("Projections").Columns(ColNum).Hidden = True  
    End If

    ColNum = ColNum + 1 ' column number always needs incremented
Next
```